# Cinema 4D animations in Three JS

Tags: animation, three.js, cinema-4d

I've been trying to set up a decent workflow for Cinema 4D and Three JS. The problem is with animations. So while I do get the models to load in .obj and .dae, animations are not working. I understand there are some limitations to how Cinema exports the file and how Three understands them.

I've also tried to include Blender into the workflow, but it unfortunately distorts the animations, and for some reason does not output working .json when I've imported them from a Cinema project.

Anyone here who figured this one out? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a code sample or a link to your scene ?

Comment: Well I've tried the different formats, and didn't really know what I should share since nothing worked. What I would really appreciate is just if someone managed to do this C4D -> ThreeJS, and what kind of quirks one needs to take into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to get simple PSR-animations working without having to touch Blender, using this Collada converter:

http://rmx.github.io/collada-converter/preview/examples/convert.html

You'll also have to modify the xml tags in the file:

https://superuser.com/questions/148024/how-to-import-mesh-animation-from-cinema4d-into-blender

Unfortunately it does not seem to handle morphs. For that I had to resort to Blender, where I created the model in C4D, imported it in Blender, baked it, then exported it as .json.

I would be very happy if this could be a little bit more simple! : )

Answer (score 1):

You can try my Cinema 4D plugin:
https://github.com/BlackDice/Cinema4D-Threejs-Exporter